# How to 'recession-proof' a 401k (least risky investments)?

Tags: united-states, 401k, investment-strategies, recession

A 401k can have risky and less risky investments.

What are recommended as the least risky investments within a 401k within the USA??

Presently most of the 401k is in conservative funds (PHYZX, MWTIX).

401k adviser has suggested an annuity (e.g. $100k, wait 2 years, gives $8200/year for life), one drawback I know of is inflation, there have to be other options.

The 'guaranteed' account (fixed income I think it's called on the 401k site) probably has a lower interest rate than the rate of inflation, so it would lose value/purchasing power.

What other kinds of investments can I do within the 401k to minimize the effects of any recession upon the 401k overall??

Actual withdrawals out of the 401k are taxed, though some of it comes back as tax refunds later.

Thank you, :) p

Comment: is the annuity inside the 401(k)? are you currently retired? are you at the age where you must make distributions?

Comment: "What other kinds of investments can I do within the 401k to minimize the effects of any recession upon the 401k overall??"  That ***must** depend on what funds the 401(k) offers.

Comment: Both PHYZX & MWTIX, being bond fund, suffer from "interest rate risk": as interest rates rise, the value drops, because people (for example) won't pay $1000 for a "used" 3% bond when they can buy a "new" 5% bond for $1000.

Comment: Do you need this money to live on?

Comment: What is a "401k adviser"??? Who is that person and why are they advising you anything? How are they getting paid?

Comment: @littleadv 401(k) providers now offer advice and managed investing.  *Maybe* that's what OP is referring to.  Or maybe it's an annuity salesman saying he's a "401k adviser" (which is *technically* true, since he's advising OP about their 401(k)).

Comment: Interest rates are supposed to fall in recessions.  That means the prices of your PHYZX & MWTIX shares would *rise* during the recession.  Thus, you're already protected.  Unfortunately, the *demand* for such bonds might also fall, thus counteracting the price rise.

Comment: I believe this is the same querant as https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/155555/pending-recession-keep-money-in-401k-or-savings-account, so some of the same background should apply -- though it might be good to edit  the relevant facts into this question so it stands alone.

Comment: Warning: Some of the worst financial mistakes I have seen people make is to get too conservative with their 401k. If you don't plan to withdraw that money in the next 10-15 years I wouldn't change my strategy at all in anticipation of recessions. You will miss out on a lot of gains, and it will cost you big. Secondly, an advisor pitching an annuity in a 401k is a HUGE red flag. Most of the time it makes no sense except to the advisor who gets a massive commission on selling annuities.

Comment: @RonJohn my point is to question OP's understanding of that advisor's motivation. See the comment by JohnFX below.

Comment: I'm stuck with the advisor (AIG is the company) since I'm not working and semi-retired until/if I get employed again and this money has to help me and my husband for a few years in addition to our SS. However, I'm not seeing any *actual real answers* to my question, what are the least risky things I can do within the 401k if I don't do the annuity?? Stuff is in bonds b/c less risky than stocks. Thank you. :)

Comment: What kinds of options does your 401k offer? Money market is usually considered less risky than stocks and bonds in that it won't lose value measured in dollars, but if the rate of return is lower than the rate of inflation then you're losing some spending value. Some money market accounts are FDIC insured, some aren't.

Comment: On the surface, the annuity sounds good because of $8,200 a year for life.  But you have to look deeper than that.  Fixed annuity? Variable annuity?  Hybrid? Is it a reputable company?  Is the principal reduced by $8,200 a year?  Does it provide for an annual penalty free withdrawal (some annuities allow 6-10% a year). Suppose you die in a few years.  What happens to the principal?  Spouse continues to receive benefits?  Suppose he/she dies soon thereafter.  Is there a death benefit to the estate?  FWIW, very little keeps up as inflation increases.

Comment: I wish there were more websites I could ask this question. The comments about money market and annuity type/change etc. are helpful. I'd just like the 401k to not *lose* too much money at best, I don't feel like it will hold *any* value ever. sigh

Answer (score 2):

### Minimize Expenses, Bond Funds

The easiest way to "Recession Proof" a 401k is to minimize what you take out of it during the Recession. The S&P 500 recovered from the 2008 crash by 2012 - so if you didn't take anything out during those 4 years, then you didn't actually lose any money. (Excepting opportunity costs, etc.)

This is why young people are told to be aggressive with their investments - they're not going to take money out in the near term, so downturns are less meaningful to them.

Otherwise, Bonds are generally considered the most resilient investment category - they should lose the least value during a recession. Comments indicate that the Mutual Funds you mentioned are Bond Funds, so it sounds like you're set there.

### Be Careful of Being Pressured

From this question and another, it looks like OP's spouse is concerned about a recession and looking to take action. While there are certainly indications that 2023 could be a rough year, a recession is far from certain.

What is certain is that some people make money selling Gold as a safe "investment" - and that financial companies make money off transaction costs, annuities with questionable fine print, etc.

So there are financial incentives for some people to sell the message that *"a recession is coming and you must take action."*

That doesn't necessarily mean that a recession is coming or that taking action is in your best interest.